# Convert email date into a datefield

Tags: coldfusion

I'm not sure if it's an ISO date or not.  When I read email from a pop server, one of the fields is called "date", and it has a string that looks like this:

> 19 Jun 2012 18:02:09 -0400

Q: Is there a routine to convert this date to a ColdFusion date variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created two variables.

```
thisdate = "19 Jun 2012 18:02:09 -0400";
thisdate = "19 Jun 2012 18:02:09";
```

I ran them through this conditional statement.

```
if (isDate(thisdate)) {
    writeOutput("It is a date!");
} else {
    writeOutput("It is NOT date!");
}
```

The first one is NOT a date. The second is a date.

Perhaps you could just look the "-0400", which is probably an offset.

You could manipulate the date to create the type of date that you really want.

```
newDate = dateFormat(thisdate, "full"); 
writeOutput(newDate);
newTime = timeFormat(thisdate, "full"); 
writeOutput(newTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [UDF](http://cflib.org/udf/DateConvertISO8601) from cflib site